# JavaFX, PieChart - How to add Data

Tags: java, javafx, pie-chart, scenebuilder

I am trying to add data to my PieChart. I was writing the code like this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD), but when I am trying to add variable implemented before it is not working. What's wrong ?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class HomeScreenController implements Initializable{


    //Counter dreams "straszny"
    public String Straszny = "Straszny";
    public double Straszny_Counter = 0;

    //Counter dreams "smieszny"
    public String Smieszny = "Śmieszny";
    public double Smieszny_Counter = 0;

    //Counter dreams "dziwny"
    public String Dziwny = "Dziwny";
    public double Dziwny_Counter = 0;

    //Counter dreams "SF"
    public String SF = "SF";
    public double SF_Counter = 0;

    //Counter dreams "straszny"
    public String Inny = "Inny";
    public double Inny_Counter = 0;

    @FXML
    private PieChart sleepTypes;

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data(Smieszny, Smieszny_Counter),
            new PieChart.Data(Straszny, Straszny_Counter),
            new PieChart.Data(Dziwny, Dziwny_Counter),
            new PieChart.Data(SF, SF_Counter),
            new PieChart.Data(Inny, Inny_Counter));

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        for(int i = 0;i<ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.size();i++)
        {
            //Check how much "strasznych" dreams is
            if(Straszny.equals(ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getType()))
            {
                Straszny_Counter++;
            }
            //Check how much "smiesznych" dreams is
            else if(Smieszny.equals(ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getType()))
            {
                Smieszny_Counter++;
            }
            //Check how much "dziwny" dreams is
            else if(Dziwny.equals(ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getType()))
            {
                Dziwny_Counter++;
            }
            //Check how much "SF" dreams is
            else if(SF.equals(ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getType()))
            {
                SF_Counter++;
            }
            //Check how much "inny" dreams is
            else if(Inny.equals(ShowDreamHistoryController.listDreams.get(i).getType()))
            {
                Inny_Counter++;
            }
        }//for

        System.out.println("Straszych: "+Straszny_Counter);
        System.out.println("Smiesznych: "+Smieszny_Counter);
        System.out.println("Dziwny: "+Dziwny_Counter);
        System.out.println("SF: "+SF_Counter);
        System.out.println("Inny: "+Inny_Counter);

        //Add Data to the chart
        sleepTypes.setData(pieChartData);
    }//init
}//class
```

[image: Here, what it looks like after compilation]

The code is working when it is like that:

```
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data(Smieszny, 1),
            new PieChart.Data(Straszny, 2),
            new PieChart.Data(Dziwny, 5),
            new PieChart.Data(SF, 1),
            new PieChart.Data(Inny, 1));
```

But I don't want that one. Any ideas what is wrong with the first code?

Comment: This is because you are making the `ObservableList pieChartData ` in the beginning and then doing changes on the integer values. Try filling the `ObservableList pieChartData`  after your `for loop`.

Comment: Of course ! its obvious. Thanks :)